# How to send SBPL byte[] to my SATO CG408TT Barcode Printer

Tags: c#

Im developing C# barcode printing project that using SATO CG408TT for the printer

This is the code I have been using for :

```
   Printer SATOPrinter = new Printer();
   List<Printer.USBInfo> USBPorts = SATOPrinter.GetUSBList();          
   SATOPrinter.Interface = Printer.InterfaceType.USB;        
   SATOPrinter.USBPortID = USBPorts[0].PortID;
   SATOPrinter.Connect();
   SATOPrinter.TestPrint(); //--> success test print
   SATOPrinter.Send(byte[] Data); //--> how to create SBPL byte[] data and send to my printer`
```

In example I want to send this SBPL :

```
<A>
<V>100<H>50<L>0404<XB>1SATO
<V>350<H>100<B>104250*12345*
<V>600<H>150<L>0101<XB> 1*12345*
<Q>1
<Z>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the Programming Reference specification for the SBPL language, they use the notation

```
'<A>'
```

for

```
'ESC A'
```

... where ESC is 1B hexadecimal. This goes for all commands.This means that your string should look something like this:

```
"\x1bA\n\x1bV100\x1bH50\x1bL0404\x1bXB1SATO\n"
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF8 encoding to get the bytes

```
            string printerData = "<A>\n" +
                                 "<V>100<H>50<L>0404<XB>1SATO\n" +
                                 "<V>350<H>100<B>104250*12345*\n" +
                                 "<V>600<H>150<L>0101<XB> 1*12345*\n" +
                                 "<Q>1\n" +
                                 "<Z>\n";
            byte[] Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(printerData);
```